# Why does webpack deal with CSS in such a strange way?

Tags: css, webpack

I'm playing around with `webpack`, which seems extremely well suited for handling JS dependencies and supports a lot of clever ways to reduce the apps footprint like code splitting. So after replacing my clumsy `gulp` tasks with a much faster and easier webpack configuration I thought let's look into replacing my SCSS/CSS pipeline too. After a little research it seems to me that webpack's approach to CSS is really strange. In every example I've seen, CSS is first written into style tags in the `index.html` file and then extracted into a file again in the next step.

Why would webpack do that? Is there some kind of rationale behind that decision that I don't understand?

Comment: depends actually, most of the time CSS files are just being bundled in Vue or other frameworks.